# Jython 2.5.1: Calling From Java into __main__ - how to pass in command line args?

Tags: command-line, jython, argv, argc

I'm using Jython from within Java; so I have a Java setup similar to below:

```
String scriptname="com/blah/myscript.py"
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(scriptname);
interpreter.execfile(is);
```

And this will (for instance) run the script below:

```
# myscript.py:
import sys

if __name__=="__main__":
    print "hello"
    print sys.argv
```

How I pass in 'commandline' arguments using this method ?
(I want to be able to write my Jython scripts so that I can also run them on the commandline with 'python script arg1 arg2').

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using Jython 2.5.2 and `runScript` didn't exist, so I had to replace it with `execfile`.  Aside from that difference, I also needed to set `argv` in the state object before creating the `PythonInterpreter` object:

```
String scriptname = "myscript.py";

PySystemState state = new PySystemState();
state.argv.append (new PyString ("arg1"));
state.argv.append (new PyString ("arg2"));

PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(null, state);
InputStream is = Tester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(scriptname);
interpreter.execfile (is);
```

The `argv` list in the state object initially has a length of 1, with an empty string in it, so the preceding code results in the output:

```
hello
['', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

If you need `argv[0]` to be the actual script name, you'd need to create the state like this:

```
PySystemState state = new PySystemState();
state.argv.clear ();
state.argv.append (new PyString (scriptname));      
state.argv.append (new PyString ("arg1"));
state.argv.append (new PyString ("arg2"));
```

Then the output is:

```
hello
['myscript.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Comment: nice one - I'm just need to check this out with my release of Jython (actually 2.5.1..not 2.5 - apologies); I'll mark as accepted ASAP. Cheers

Comment: Also : 'runScript' was my method - I have wrapped the class in my code - I have corrected original post to use 'execfile'

Comment: Yup , works a treat; noticed that there appears to be a documented method to retrieve systemState, but doesn't seem to be there on my distro : http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#getSystemState%28%29 - thanks accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those people whom the above solution does not work, try the below. This works for me on jython version 2.7.0

```
String[] params = {"get_AD_accounts.py","-server", "http://xxxxx:8080","-verbose", "-logLevel", "CRITICAL"};
```

The above replicates the command below. i.e. each argument and its value is separate element in params array.

***jython get_AD_accounts.py -logLevel CRITICAL -server http://xxxxxx:8080 -verbose***

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), params);

PySystemState state = new PySystemState() ;

InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\projectfolder\\get_AD_accounts.py");
            PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, state);

PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, state);
interp.execfile(is);
```